# How to use random to choose colors

Tags: python, random, colors

I'm trying to make a little program to learn more, but am stuck when it comes to using random.

Here is an example of what I'm going off of https://trinket.io/Python/3338c95430

I've tried using random.randrange, random.choice, random.random with everything for them and it sends an error code saying random doesn't have a function of randrange, choice, or random.

```
import turtle, math, random, time

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('grey')
Rocket = turtle.Turtle()
Rocket.speed(0)
Rocket.color('red') ## this is what i want to randomize
rotate=int(90)

def drawCircles(t,size):
    for i in range(15):
        t.circle(size)
        size=size-10
def drawSpecial(t,size,repeat):
    for i in range(repeat):
        drawCircles(t,size)
        t.right(360/repeat)
drawSpecial(Rocket,100,10)
```

Eventually I would like to implement more randomized processes like the size and placement but for now I'm just focusing on color.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without using additional imports it's fairly simple:

```
turtle.colormode(255) # sets the color mode to RGB

R = random.randrange(0, 256, 100) # last value optional (step) 
B = random.randrange(0, 256)
G = random.randrange(0, 256)

# using step allows more control if needed
# for example the value of `100` would return `0`, `100` or `200` only

Rocket.color(R, G, B) ## randomized from values above
```

Using randomized values of (`200`,`255`,`23`):

[image]

> <sub>**EDIT**: Regarding "would i just change the turtle.colormode()
>   to Rocket.colormode() for the next one?"</sub>

The way I would recommend doing it would be to create a function:

```
def drawColor():

    turtle.colormode(255)

    R = random.randrange(0, 256)
    B = random.randrange(0, 256)
    G = random.randrange(0, 256)

    return R, G, B

Rocket.color(drawColor())
```

This way you can call `drawColor()` anytime you want a new color.

Now that you have the basics of randomizing colors for your drawing you can get quite creative with the values for some awesome looking results (adjust integers to your liking):

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import turtle, math, random, time

def drawColor(a, b, o):
    turtle.colormode(255)
    R = random.randrange(a, b, o) # last value is step (optional)
    B = random.randrange(a, b, o)
    G = random.randrange(a, b, o)
    # print(R, G, B)
    return R, G, B

def drawRocket(offset):
    Rocket = turtle.Turtle()
    Rocket.speed(0)
    Rocket.color(drawColor(20, 100, 1)) # start (0-256), end (0-256), offset 
    rotate=int(random.randrange(90))
    drawSpecial(Rocket,random.randrange(0, 10), offset)

def drawCircles(t,size):
    for i in range(30):
        t.circle(size)
        size = size - 20

def drawSpecial(t,size,repeat):
    for i in range(repeat):
        drawCircles(t,size)
        t.right(360/repeat)

def drawMain(x, y):
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor(drawColor(0, 20, 2))

    for i in range(3): # iterations
        drawRocket(x)
        x+=y
        # print(x)

drawMain(2, 10) # offset, step
input("Press ENTER to exit")
```

Comment: So I tried this and got this error " R = random.randrange(0, 256, 100) # last value optional (step) 
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randrange'  but i tried it in python idle and it worked, now i would be implementing it on other ones as well so would i just change the turtle.colormode() to Rocket.colormode() for the next one?

Comment: @jman8453: What I would recommend is to create a function for the color, then anytime you want to call `Rocket.colormode()` you can get the random color; I'll edit the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you so much, I honestly was not expecting much help after i couldn't find anything about my problem doing a lot of searching online. I'm really excited to learn more about all of this and make something of my own but so far this has been a really fun learning expirience!

Answer (score 4):

One way to generate random colors (assuming RGB) within the 256 range is to use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

```
import numpy as np

color = tuple(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))
print(color)
```

As per jpmc26's comment, another method without requiring Numpy is to use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) if you're using Python 3.6+. This is probably a better option since importing Numpy just to create 3 random integers is overkill.

```
import random

color = tuple(random.choices(range(256), k=3))
print(color)
```

Example random RGB output

> (248, 88, 28)
>
> (165, 248, 150)
>
> (188, 29, 135)

Comment: so idle keeps telling me an error that there is no module named numpy would it be because im using turtle or something?

Comment: Its another package, you can install it with `python -m pip install numpy`

Comment: `Numpy` is a powerful package for computing with N-dimensional array object. It does not make much sense to install (not even import IMO) it just for creating 3 random integers.

Comment: I agree it mostly used for numerical processing and is probably overkill but its just another option to generate random RGB colors :)

Comment: With Python 3.6+, you can use `random.choices(range(256), k=3)` without requiring numpy.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's the probably the best method

Answer (score 4):

`random.choice` returns a random element from a sequence, just pass it a list with the values you want to choose from:

```
rand_color = random.choice(['blue', 'red'])
Rocket.color(rand_color)
```

Comment: ok so i did it wrong with random choice, i thought it would go more like    
    Rocket.color(random.choice(rand_color))  thanks for that!